# Highlight duplicate cells without counting blank spaces in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to highlight any duplicate cells in the range C2:G6. The conditional formating

```
=countif($C$2:$G$6,C2)>1
```

does not count two cells differring by some blank spaces.

I would consider two cells to be identical if they differ only by blank spaces. I tried to use Trim,

```
=countif(map(flatten($C$2:$G$6),lambda(s,trim(s)),C2)>1
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM($C$2:$G$6)), TRIM(C2)) > 1)
```

With a couple of changes your original formula will also work:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),COUNTIF(MAP(FLATTEN($C$2:$G$6),LAMBDA(s,TRIM(s))),TRIM(C2))>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another condition to your formula:

```cpp
=AND(C2<>"",COUNTIF($C$2:$G$6,C2)>1)
```